# Transformers headroom and "mandatory" components

Tags: power-supply, transformer, certification

I have calculated the maximum (Worst Case) current consumption of my circuit to be 88mA. Looking at transformers [I found one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/triad-magnetics/F24-045-C2/237-1553-ND/3986433) at an specified max output current of 90mA for parallel winding which is my case. The next available component has a max current output of 200mA.

Q1: am I cutting it too short if I select the 90mA transformer? is there any derating that I should take into account such as temperature or saturation current as for inductors?

Q2: On the primary winding connected to AC mains. Are elements such as a fuse and a Y2 capacitor mandatory to pass electrical certifications?

Thank you

Comment: what is the measured current consumption?

Comment: The circuit has not been built. Is the analytical calculation of the WC consumption

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a bridge rectifier and smoothing capacitor that feeds your load then it's likely that your prefered transformer is too feeble: -

[image]

This picture came from [this pragmatic doument](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwivi4a90sbcAhXkA8AKHRBpDxoQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hammondmfg.com%2Fpdf%2F5c007.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3-oycQkmf0vMLPJPNa-yoK) produced by Hammond.

What you have to remember is that the DC output is going to be 1.4142 x the RMS secondary voltage (minus a couple of diode forward drops) and with a 12 volt secondary, the DC voltage will be about 15.6 volts. If you are pulling off a current of 88 mA, that's a load VA of 1.37 and the transformer is only rated for 1.1 VA (12 volt x 0.09 amps).

Comment: Is this calculation only valid for a no-load circuit? The specification says 12V at full load so I would imagine that the output voltage will be 12V-(0.7*2)?

Comment: The output DC level from a bridge and capacitor is the RMS AC voltage into the bridge multiplied by \$\sqrt2\$ and then subtracted by 2*0.7 volts. That is at full load and of course there will be ripple to consider.